# How to hide the CALayer's borders without causing rendering issue in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiview, xamarin.ios, calayer

I am having three UIView's one after the other horizontally, with each UiView.Layer.BorderColor set to Black and UiView.Layer.BorderWidth set to 0.25f like shown below. So this gives a border look for each of the view.

[image: UiView's with borders applied]

Now i have a requirement to only display the horizontal borders of the UiViews. Hence i create a mask layer and set path and frame to that mask layer to apply clip. Please refer the code snippet below to give you an idea of what am doing.

```
foreach (UIView UiView in myViews)
        {
            UiView.Layer.BorderColor = Color.Black.ToCGColor();
            UiView.Layer.BorderWidth = 0.25f;
            UIBezierPath maskPath = null;
            CAShapeLayer maskLayer = new CAShapeLayer();
            maskLayer.Frame = UiView.Bounds;
            // Applying Clip to my layer
            maskPath = UIBezierPath.FromRect(new CGRect(UiView.Bounds.Left + 0.5, UiView.Bounds.Top, UiView.Bounds.Width - 1, UiView.Bounds.Height));
            maskLayer.Path = maskPath.CGPath;
            view.Layer.Mask = maskLayer;
        }
```

Yes i am aware that whatever the bounds i set for the maskPath is the Visible region, so given that each UiView is 60 in width , my visible region according to what i have written in code is , from 0.5 pixel upto 59.5 pixel of each UIView . Thus eliminating the borders present in the pixels from 0 to 0.5 and from 59.5 to 60. Hope this part is clear for you. Please refer the below image for a visual representation of my mask area. The Yellow borders denotes the mask bounds.

[image: borderClip]

Now all is fine , but this 0.5 pixels border which is hidden causes a white space in my top and bottom borders of the UiView's put together continuously. Please refer the below image with the circled spots highlighting the void spaces in the top and bottom.
[image: final result]

This can be easily reproduced in code too. Please suggest me on how to overcome this problem. What am i doing wrong. I know this is a very small blank space of half a pixel which is barely visible to the naked eye most of the times, but it will not be visually pleasing for my grid view application.

**PS : Am developing in Xamarin.iOS , however native iOS solutions will also be helpful.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

**Try this for Swift.**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view3: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var borderwidth = CGFloat()
        borderwidth = 5

        let topBorder = CALayer()
        topBorder.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        topBorder.frame = CGRect(x: self.view1.frame.origin.x, y: self.view1.frame.origin.y, width: self.view3.frame.origin.x + self.view3.frame.size.width - self.view1.frame.origin.x, height: borderwidth)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(topBorder)

        let bottomBorder = CALayer()
        bottomBorder.backgroundColor =  UIColor.black.cgColor
        bottomBorder.frame = CGRect(x: self.view1.frame.origin.x, y: self.view1.frame.origin.y + self.view1.frame.size.height - borderwidth, width: self.view3.frame.origin.x + self.view3.frame.size.width - self.view1.frame.origin.x, height: borderwidth)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(bottomBorder)

    }

}
```

**See this screenshot** : [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoZFb.png)

Comment: HI @Dixit , Thanks for your time. It makes sense totally. But my task in hand is that , currently we are achieving this requirement only by using multiple layers(left, top, right, bottom) as you have suggested and hence in order to optimize it, am planning to cut down this to only one layer (mask layer) and hence the problem.

Comment: Could you please post the codes you are using to mask ?

Comment: @VimalPrabhu nop i don't use mask.but i telling you above code is working fine.

Comment: yes the above code you posted will work fine in all the patforms, and this is the approach we have currently adopted too. We have one layer each for each side of the UIView. My task is to improve performance by reducing the number of layers to one

Answer (score 0):

Masking is the problem. Try like this.

```
view.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
view.Layer.AllowsEdgeAntialiasing = true;
layer.BorderColor = color.ToCGColor();
layer.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
if (layer.SuperLayer == null && layer.SuperLayer != view.Layer)
    view.Layer.AddSublayer(layer);
view.Layer.BorderColor = Color.Transparent.ToCGColor();
layer.Frame = new CGRect(view.Bounds.Left, view.Bounds.Bottom - 0.5f, view.Bounds.Right, view.Bounds.Bottom);
```